# Looking for help on why GPU is not used when I train a Pytorch model

Tags: pytorch, gpu, pytorch-dataloader

The machine I am using for training has 4 GPUs.  I am "moving" classifier, loss function and tensors to GPU.   But when I run `nvidia-smi` on the machine while training is ongoing, I see GPU utilization is very low (3%) on one core and 0 on other cores.

Questions I have are

1. Is there an easier approach to ask Pytorch to use GPU and as many cores as available without me having to do so many `.to(device)` all over the place
2. Is there something other than `.to(device)` that is needed to use GPU?
3. Is there a way to see if training is happening on CPU vs GPU or is running nvidia-smi on the machine and looking at GPU utilization the only way?
4. How do I interpret GPU utilization of 3% in `nvidia-smi`.  Does it mean CPU is being used in many places?  If yes, is there a way to debug what is making the training use CPU?
5. Will setting `num_workers` to number of available cores in `DataLoader` class be enough to use multiple GPU cores?  Is there any generic way to automatically learn number of GPU cores available?

Code used to train

```
random.seed(1234)
np.random.seed(1234)
torch.manual_seed(1234)
torch.cuda.manual_seed(1234)
torch.backends.cudnn.deterministic = True

start_time = time.time()
clf = MLP(len(X_training[0]), hidden_size=[100, 100, 100, 100, 100])
#Move to GPU if available
use_gpu = torch.cuda.is_available()
device = torch.device('cuda' if use_gpu else 'cpu')

# Define the loss function and optimizer
optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(clf.parameters(), lr=8e-4)
clf = clf.to(device)
loss_function = nn.BCELoss()
loss_function = loss_function.to(device)

# Run the training loop
# per_epoch_precision = []
# per_epoch_recall = []
for epoch in range(0, 150):
    # Set current loss value
    current_loss = 0.0
    dataset = MyDataset(X_training, y_training, use_gpu)
    kwargs = {'num_workers': 1, 'pin_memory': True} if use_gpu else {}
    trainloader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=10000, shuffle=True, **kwargs)

    # Iterate over the DataLoader for training data
    clf.train()  # set to train mode
    for i, data in enumerate(trainloader):
        # Get inputs
        inputs, targets = data
        inputs = inputs.to(device)
        targets = targets.to(device)

        # Zero the gradients
        optimizer.zero_grad()

        # Perform forward pass
        outputs = clf(inputs)

        # Compute loss
        targets = targets.float().unsqueeze(1)
        loss = loss_function(outputs, targets)

        # Perform backward pass
        loss.backward()

        # Perform optimization
        optimizer.step()

        # Print statistics
        current_loss += loss.item()
        if i % 20000 == 19999:
            print("Loss after mini-batch %5d: %.3f" % (i + 1, current_loss / 500))
            current_loss = 0.0

# Process is complete.
print("Training process has finished.")
print(f"Train time is {time.time() - start_time}")
```

```
class MyDataset(Dataset):

  def __init__(self, x, y, use_gpu=False):
    x = x.astype(np.float32)
    self.x_train = torch.from_numpy(x)
    self.y_train = torch.from_numpy(y.values)
    if use_gpu:
        device = torch.device("cuda")
        self.x_train.to(device)
        self.y_train.to(device)
    # self.y_train = torch.LongTensor(y.values, dtype=torch.int)


  def __len__(self):
    return len(self.y_train)
  
  def __getitem__(self,idx):
    return self.x_train[idx],self.y_train[idx]
```

```
class MLP(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, act_fn=nn.ReLU(), use_dropout=False, drop_rate=0.25):
        super(MLP, self).__init__()
        self.input_size = input_size
        self.hidden_size = hidden_size
        self.layers = nn.Sequential()
        if use_dropout:
            self.layers.append(nn.Dropout(p=drop_rate))
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(self.input_size, self.hidden_size[0]))
        self.layers.append(act_fn)                
        for i in range(1, len(hidden_size)):
            if use_dropout:
                self.layers.append(nn.Dropout(p=drop_rate))
            self.layers.append(nn.Linear(self.hidden_size[i - 1], self.hidden_size[i]))
            self.layers.append(act_fn)
        
        if use_dropout:
            self.layers.append(nn.Dropout(p=drop_rate))
        self.layers.append(nn.Linear(self.hidden_size[-1], 1))
        self.layers.append(nn.Sigmoid())      

    def forward(self, x):
        return self.layers(x)
```

Comment: Are you using MacOS? Any luck getting the GPUs going?